# Greedy repeatable capture group with negative lookahead not working

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex:

```
((?:test)+)(?!$)
```

That I want to match only if the last repeatable capture group ("test") is *not* ending the string.

So it should match:

```
sometesttesttesta
```

But not:

```
sometesttesttest
```

For some reason it keeps matching up until the last "test" instance (`testtest` in `sometesttesttest`), as if it wasn't greedy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need `(?>(?:test)+)(?!$)`, an atomic grouping to prevent backtracking.

Comment: Thanks for the provided answer. So when it comes to atomic groups and  greediness, the longest string (greediest match) is tested first and then it exits, hence being able to match `testtesttest` here?

Comment: It is more a backtracking related problem: the quantified part can match a string differently, and the negative lookahead can trigger backtracking once the currently matched substring does not fit the lookahead restriction. Since the lookahead is FALSE at first, the quantified part yields the latest submatch and the lookahead pattern is retried, and if it succeeds (and it succeeds in your case) there is a match. When using atomic groups, no backtracking into the quantified pattern is allowed.